# How to get a specific attribute from an object list?

Tags: java, wicket

I've an array keeping a list of `Group` objects. I want to set this list to the `DropDownChoice` component. However I want to show the end user only the name attribute of `Group` objects, and then get the selected values' id attribute to add database. What to do?

```
private List<Group> groupTypes;
DatabaseApp db = new DatabaseApp();
groupTypes = db.getGroups();
groupDropDownChoice = new DropDownChoice("type", groupTypes);
...
...
addUserForm.add(new Button("submit"){
            @Override
            public void onSubmit(){
                Group group = (Group) groupDropDownChoice.getModelObject(); 
...
...
            db.addUser(group.getId(), den, name, login, email, password1);
```

### DatabaseApp.java

```
public List<Group> getGroups() throws SQLException{
        List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM [GROUP]";
            Statement statement = db.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);

            while(result.next()){
                int id = result.getInt("ID");
                String name = result.getString("NAME");
                groups.add(new Group(id, name));
            }
            result.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new SQLException(ex.getMessage());
        }
            return groups;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DropDownChoice` has another constructor accepting an additional parameter of an `IChoiceRenderer` that allows control of what's displayed and what's sent back with the form.

See [this example](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket14/compref/?wicket%3abookmarkablePage=%3aorg.apache.wicket.examples.compref.DropDownChoicePage).

In your code, an implementation could look approximately like

```
private List<Group> groupTypes;
DatabaseApp db = new DatabaseApp();
groupTypes = db.getGroups();
groupDropDownChoice = new DropDownChoice("type", groupTypes, new IChoiceRenderer(){
    @Override
    public Object getDisplayValue(Object object) {
        return ((Group) object).getName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdValue(Object object, int index) {
        return Integer.toString(index);
    }
});
...
...
addUserForm.add(new Button("submit"){
            @Override
            public void onSubmit(){
                Group group = (Group) groupDropDownChoice.getModelObject(); 
...
...
            db.addUser(group.getId(), den, name, login, email, password1);
```

Comment: I've found same exercise, I've tried it but it gives compile error at casting (Group) groupDropDownChoice.getModelObject(); "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to set model object on null model of component: form:type"

Comment: Is that error on a submit without selecting from the dropdown or after an actual selection?

Answer (score 0):

You're just creating the `DropDownChoice` directly from the list of groups. It seems to me that what you really want is a model for the list of groups; see the [`IModel` documentation](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/index.html?org/apache/wicket/model/IModel.html). Then you can create a custom model that returns only the name of a group instead of the whole `Group` object.